# Sticky footer driving me nuts - please help?

Tags: footer, sticky

I've been looking at this for days, and I've searched and searched, maybe I just can't see the forest for the trees, but if anyone could shed some insight, I'd be really grateful.

Ok, I have this sticky footer that sort of is at the top of the page and scrolling down the page, the bar is always at the botom of the screen.

It works perfectly on my PC, but I can't see it on other PC's I test.  Same exact set up, the paths to the images are there.  I just can't seem to figureit out, I fee like I'm going banana's!

**html code is:**

```
<body id="home">
    <div class="wrap">
    <!-- Header -->
    <div id="header">
    </div>         
    <div id="slideshow-container"> 
        <div id="slideshow"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- // Header -->
        <div id="main" class="clearfix">      
    <!-- Content -->
    <div id="content">
  </div>
    <!-- // Content -->     
    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div id="sidebar">                
    </div>            
    <!-- // sidebar -->         
    </div>
<!-- // Wrap end -->            
    <div id="footer" class="clearfix">
        <div class="wrap">
            <div class="clearfix">
                        </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Ok, you just can't see the images... what is going on - I feel so retarded!!

CSS:

```
body{
    background: url(../images/bg_body.png) center 0 #ffffff repeat-x;
    font-size: 62.5%;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #666666;
    padding: 0 0 50px 0;    
    height: 100%;

#footer{
    background: url(../images/bg_footer.gif) center 0 repeat-x;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;    
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
}

#footer .wrap{  
    background: url(../images/bg_footer_wrap.png) center 0 no-repeat;
    padding: 7px 0 0 0;
    height: 70px;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a good long look at [CssStickyFooter.com](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/) and compare it to your code.

The immediately obvious thing is that your HTML is broken (body and wrap are never closed) and that ".clearfix" (not defined in posted CSS, btw) is applied all over the place.

Answer (score 1):

Found a great sticky footer solution today. Hope it helps, seems to be the simplest solution to me:

```
<style type="text/css">
   html,body {
      height:100%
   }

   #wrapper {
      min-height:100%;
      margin-bottom:-150px; /* negative total computed height of footer */
   }

   #footer_padding {
      height:150px; /* total computed height of footer */
   }

   #footer {
      height:100px;
      margin-top:50px;
   }
</style>    


<div id="wrapper">

   <div>some content...</div>

   <div id="footer_padding"></div>

</div>

<div id="footer"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will find on this github repository ([Bredele css sticky footer](https://github.com/bredele/css-bundle/tree/master/sticky-footer)) two versions of sticky footers : one with a header and an other one without.

Both these versions use display:table (works with IE8 and IE6/7 with polyfill) with no extra markups, **no clearfix** (instead CssStickyFooter) and a flexible content height.

Hope it'll be helpful!

Olivier

Comment: wouldn't *someone* say that you are using tables for layout? Even if it is a display property...